# How to use Laravel Cache::remember with a callback function

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-cache

I would like to reference a private function as the third parameter to the Cache::remember function.

Instead of this *(try{}catch() was removed for a cleaner code)*:

```
class ApiController extends Controller
{

    public function index(){
        $data = Cache::remember('dataKey', 60, function () {
            return Model::multipleMethodsHere()->get();
        });
        return response()->json($data,200);
    }
}
```

I'd like to do this:

```
class ApiController extends Controller
{

    public function index(){
        $data = Cache::remember('dataKey', 60, $this->getIndex());
        return response()->json($data,200);
    }
    private function getIndex(){
        return Model::....->get();
    }
}
```

I got this error if I try to reference a private function.

```
Argument 3 passed to Illuminate\\Cache\\Repository::remember() must be an instance of Closure, instance of Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection given
```

Is it possible ? If yes, how should I do ?

Comment: Is there a reason why the `Cache::remember` cannot be a part of the `getIndex` function, with parameters such as `'dataKey'` could be passed into it right?

Comment: @Coola No real reason. I just wanted to separate the cache logic from the model fetch logic.

Comment: I think making Cache part of the `getIndex` function would be the way to go. It will probably be easier. Not sure if you put the `$this->getIndex()` in a closure if it would work.

Comment: @Coola You are right, I guess it's not possible at the moment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments in the discussion to the OP, re-strategize the `Cache:remember` to be a part of the `getIndex` function like:

```php
class ApiController extends Controller
{

    public function index(){
        $data = $this->getIndex();
        return response()->json($data,200);
    }

    private function getIndex(string $dataKey = 'dataKey', int $time = 60){
        return Cache::remember($dataKey, $time, function () {
               return Model::....->get();
            })
          
    }
}
```